# Replacing <a> with Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, replace, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to scan a document and remove specific files that are stored as attachments. I want to note however that the value was removed in-line.

Eg.

```
<a href="...">File Download</a>
```

Converted to:

```
File Removed
```

Here is what I tried:

```
@doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html).to_html
@doc.search('a').each do |attachment|
    attachment.remove
    attachment.content = "REMOVED"

    # ALSO TRIED:
    attachment.content = "REMOVED"
end
```

The second one does replace the anchor text but keeps the href and the user can still download the value.

How can I replace the anchor value and change it to a < p> with a new string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use combination of [`create_element`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FDocument:create_element) and [`replace`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node:replace) to achieve that. Find the comments inline below.

```
html = '<a href="...">File Download</a>'
dom = Nokogiri::HTML(html) # parse with nokogiri
dom.to_s # original content
#=> "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body><a href=\"...\">File Download</a></body></html>\n"

# scan the dom for hyperlinks
dom.css('a').each do |a|
  node = dom.create_element 'p' # create paragraph element
  node.inner_html = "REMOVED" # add content you want
  a.replace node # replace found link with paragraph
end
dom.to_s # modified html
#=> "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body><p>REMOVED</p></body></html>\n"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Your solution was actually much better than the work around I used.
Thank you :D